# How to log the updated count value in react?

Tags: reactjs

Why the updated count value is not logged while clicking the button. It always logs the previous count value on button click. Here is the code -

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function updateCount() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => updateCount()}>Show alert</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

on react when your state depends on old state value you must update it like this :

```
function updateCount() {
    setCount(oldCount=>oldCount+ 1);
    console.log(count);
 }
```

and you must remember updating the state is not instant action it is super fast, but it take few milliseconds

Comment: Thanks for this but can you please tell why should we update like this? and also doing it this way doesn't log the updated value.

Comment: @HarshitBadolla as I said react not update your state instantly it is so fast but still not instant by using this method in update state react guarantees your state value is the last state value before it changes it again so you must use this method when your state depends on old state for more info read this article https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/

Answer (score 1):

I am learning React recently and I was facing the exact same problem as you. The reason console.log gives you the previous value as mentioned by Mohammad is because in the same method you are logging and updating the value and they happen together. If you simply put the console.log below the function then it will show you the updated one every time as it finished updating the value before logging.

```
const incrementCount = (increment) => {
    setCount(count + increment);
  };
  console.log(count);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always log the latest value, you could just do this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log(count);

  function updateCount() {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => updateCount()}>Show alert</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason why in your code the log function logs an outdated value is because of `closure` - the `count` value is a `const`, and it is set when the component is first rendered. So when you click the button, the value of count is not the new value, but the one it was when it was first rendered (i.e. -> always going to be one less than you expect).

In this code, log happens on every re-render. Since clicking the button calls `setCount`, the state changes, and a re-render occurs. When that happens, the log is executed, and you get the latest value :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that the React lifecycle works.  The `console.log` of your value will use the value of `count` **at the time of render**.

Render --> Execute ALL functions with the given state values --> Check for state changes --> Render --> Execute ALL functions with the new state values

Each render is with STATIC values.

If you want to see an output to the console of your count, you'll need to use a `useEffect`.

Comment: I would disagree - `useEffect` is for side effects, which are  `modifies some state variable value(s) outside its local environment`. Since `count` is local, there's no need for `useEffect`. Although it would work, I don't think its a great idea.